# Pandas cut() creating less bins

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to use pd.cut() to create 3 bins with the following code:

```
cut_bins= [0,139.99,199.99,250]
cut_labels = ['Set1', 'Set2', 'Set3']
pima1['G_set'] = pd.cut(pima1['G'],bins=cut_bins,labels=cut_labels)
print(pima1['G_set'].unique())
```

But the output only gives me 2 bins:

```
[Set1, Set2, NaN]
Categories (2, object): [Set1 < Set2]
```

Is there something wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends of data, `NaN` means data outside of bins:

```
cut_bins= [0,139.99,199.99,250]
cut_labels = ['Set1', 'Set2', 'Set3']

pima1 = pd.DataFrame({'G':[150, 200, 300]})

pima1['G_set'] = pd.cut(pima1['G'],bins=cut_bins,labels=cut_labels)
print(pima1['G_set'])
0    Set2
1    Set3
2     NaN
Name: G_set, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Set1 < Set2 < Set3]
```

Or:

```
pima1 = pd.DataFrame({'G':[0, 150, 200]})

pima1['G_set'] = pd.cut(pima1['G'],bins=cut_bins,labels=cut_labels)
print(pima1['G_set'])
0     NaN
1    Set2
2    Set3
Name: G_set, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Set1 < Set2 < Set3]
```

If need `0` in bins is necessary add `include_lowest=True` parameter:

```
pima1['G_set'] = pd.cut(pima1['G'],bins=cut_bins,labels=cut_labels, include_lowest=True)
print(pima1['G_set'])
0    Set1
1    Set2
2    Set3
Name: G_set, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Set1 < Set2 < Set3]
```